# send images to kinect as input instead of camera feed

Tags: image-processing, camera, kinect, openni

I want to send my images to Kinect SDK either OpenNI or windows SDK for Kinect sdk to tell me the position of a user's hand or head and ..
I don't want to use kinect's camera feed. The images are from a paper which I want to do some image processing on them and I need to work exactly on same images so can not use my own body as input to Kinect camera.

I don't matter between Kinect sdk of Microsoft or the OpenNI thing, it just needs to be able to get my rgb and depth images as input instead of Kinect camera's one.

Is it possible? If yes how can I do it?

Comment: What would the original source of the images (is it taken from a Kinect, or is it from some other camera system that has both RGB and depth)?  Could it be something like a .XEF / .XED recording from a Kinect, reused multiple times?  And what version of the SDK (v1.8 or v2)?

Comment: It's from Kinect and is the dataset for a paper so I can not recreate them. no Kinect studio .xed files exist for it either.

Answer (score 0):

I subscribe to the same question. I want to feed a Kinect face detection app to read images from the hard drive and return the Animation Units of the recognized face. I want to train a classifier for facial emotion recognition using Animation Units as input and features.

Thanks,
Daniel.